# Connection error: Unable to connect cassandra from host machine

Tags: cassandra, virtualbox

I have setup cassandra in ubuntu on a virtual box. Now  192.168.56.101 is the ip address is visible to the host . I want configure cassandra to access from my host machine.

In cassandra.yaml , I have changed the listen_address to 192.168.56.101 and restarted the service.
But when I tried to access from virtual box machine itself by using

*cqlsh 192.168.56.101*

, I am getting the following error:

```
*Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.56.101': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.56.101', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})*
```

Comment: `listen port to 192.168.56.101`? 
is it `listen_address:  192.168.56.101`?

Comment: Thanks @ruhul. Corrected the typo .

Comment: Its hard to tell whats wrong in here from provided information. Please check if ip/port is accessible from that maching. And cassandra is actually running on 9042 port. `netstat -antp | grep 9042` could give you a hint.